# Populate NSMutableArray with CCSprites via for loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, sprite

Hey guys, using obj-c and the cocos2d framework;
How would I populate an NSMutableArray with CCSprite's with a for-loop to reduce code.
I have +100 sprites/images that need to go into this array, so a for-loop is necessary.

This is my current code:

```
_backgrounds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:31];
for (int i = 31; i > 1; i--){
        [_backgrounds addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"background_%d.png", i]]];
    }
```

Im looking for something along the lines of this: (Although this code doesnt work),
for (int i = 31; i > 1; i--){
               [*backgrounds addObject:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background*%d.png", i]];
    }

Thanks in advanced,
Oliver.

Comment: It looks like you have already written the code to do what you describe. What's your question?

Comment: Basically i get an errror in console:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'

Comment: Well, the error is saying that you are attempting to insert a nil object. In this case your CCSpriteFrameCache is not being created correctly. Are you sure that you are referencing the right file and that the object is being set? Try to create the object before adding it and then NSLog the object to make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Hmm, I havent initialised or defined anything for the CCSpriteFrameCache, I found this code from the internet, modified it with my NSMutableArray and put it in.

How would I init a CCSpriteFrameCache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are your shared CCSpriteFrameCache does not contain any values. You must populate it prior to accessing anything from it.

Comment: I added this line into the init{ method:

[[CCSpriteFrameCache alloc] init];

This causes the same error:

2011-02-17 13:46:26.875 SS2D[699:207] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'background_31.png' not found
2011-02-17 13:46:26.880 SS2D[699:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'

All the images are in xcode, ill reimport them now to double check.

Comment: Okay I solved it, thanks anyway:

 for (int i = 31; i > 1; i--){
  [_backgrounds addObject:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"background_%d.png", i]]];

}